# iPhone Vs browser : CSS for right align clear icon in text box

Tags: iphone, css, textbox, css-float

I have seen same kind of issues in stack overflow itself. Still asking it because I am facing the following issue.

1. I have a textbox which has a clear icon on the right side.
2. And in the textbox there is a smartfill (autofilling data).
3. Need this to work fine in desktop browser / iphone browser / or in any mobile browser. !

#### HTML

```html
<div class="outerWrapper">
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <label>Smartfill box 
            <span class="ui-icon-delete"></span>                                                                      
            <input type="text" placeholder="" onkeydown="smartfill()" autocomplete="off" />
            <div id="smartFill1" class="smartFillBox">
                <li><a  href="#"><div>first</div>starts here</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#"><div>Second</div>Goes here</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#"><div>Third</div>Goes here</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#"><div>Fourth</div>Goes here</a></li>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
/* Main css --------------------*/
.outerWrapper label input[type="text"], .outerWrapper label input[type="url"], .outerWrapper label input[type="email"], .outerWrapper label input[type="password"], .outerWrapper label input[type="tel"] {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="url"], input[type="email"], input[type="password"], input[type="tel"] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #E1E1E1 inset;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 98%;
}
.outerWrapper label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

#mainContainer {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

/* site css --------------------*/
.ui-icon-delete {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url("http://www.autoweek.com/assets/losangeles/closeButton.png");
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0.3%;
    top: 36px;
    width: 4%;
    display: inline;
}
.smartFillBox {
    height: 50px;
    margin: -1px 0 0;
    width: 98%;
    display: block;
}
.smartFillBox li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CECECE;
    border-left: 1px solid #CECECE;
    border-right: 1px solid #CECECE;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JsFiddle link for **my issue** is here : http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/ze3sA/

Here is a related link: http://jsfiddle.net/PJZmv/801/

I have 3 elements. 1)input-text-box 2)clear-icon 3)smartfill-div. I am not able to relate these three accordingly! I tried jsfiddle-related-link(given above) still I am getting the same issue. Not able to align correctly.

Comment: Kindly check your fiddle it has lots of mistakes.

Comment: the related link have your answer then what are you looking for..?

Comment: I am getting different view in iphone and in desktop browser(with mobile header). The icon not at all coming correctly in the position where i needed.

Comment: Use media queries for it.

Comment: And one more thing. I have 3 elements. 1)input-text-box 2)clear-icon 3)smartfill-div. I am not able to relate these three accordingly! (I tried jsfiddle-related-link i given in my post.)